# How do I update item in database with TYPEORM?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, typeorm, put

Trying to have my the title and description parameters of my database updated.

I've successfully built post and get routes for my data, but keep running into general 500 error for the put route when I test it on Postman. I know it's got to be something wrong with my controller.

My Imports:

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response, Router } from 'express'
import { isEmpty } from 'class-validator'
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm'
import multer, { FileFilterCallback } from 'multer'
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'

import User from '../entities/User'
import Sub from '../entities/Sub'
```

My routing:

```
const router = Router()

router.put('/:name', updateSub)
```

My controller:

```
const updateSub = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const name = req.params.name
  const { description, title } = req.body
  
  try {
    const subUpdate = await Sub.update(name, { description, title })
    return res.json(subUpdate)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong' })
  }
}
```

EDIT Added Sub.ts entity:

```
import {
    Entity as TOEntity,
    Column,
    Index,
    ManyToOne,
    JoinColumn,
    OneToMany,
  } from 'typeorm'
  
  import Entity from './Entity'
  import User from './User'
  import Post from './Post'
  import { Expose } from 'class-transformer'
  
  @TOEntity('subs')
  export default class Sub extends Entity {
    constructor(sub: Partial<Sub>) {
      super()
      Object.assign(this, sub)
    }
  
    @Index()
    @Column({ unique: true })
    name: string
  
    @Column()
    title: string
  
    @Column({ type: 'text', nullable: true })
    description: string
  
    @Column({ nullable: true })
    imageUrn: string
  
    @Column({ nullable: true })
    bannerUrn: string
  
    @Column()
    username: string
  
    @ManyToOne(() => User)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'username', referencedColumnName: 'username' })
    user: User
  
    @OneToMany(() => Post, (post) => post.sub)
    posts: Post[]
```

Comment: What about your Sub.update method?

Comment: What about it? I want to update my Sub data (description and title) when given the name.

Comment: Might an error be inside it?

Comment: Any ideas on what the error could be? I have had no issues with my GET routing which has a similar syntax:
```
try {
    const sub = new Sub({ name, description, title, user })
    await sub.save()

    return res.json(sub)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong' })
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can get more information on error origin by removing that try/catch block. Or log the error, or throw it, to see where exactly is the error

Comment: Removed the try catch block. Now I'm receiving a "error: invalid input syntax for type integer: "testname"

Where testname is my given name parameter. Why would it be looking for a number?

Comment: Can you add more code regarding update method, in your question?

Comment: Added additional code. My PostgreSQL database already has data in it. I want to update the title and description based on the name. I would think sending a put request on Postman to http://localhost:5000/api/subs/testname with `{
"description": "My updated description",
"title": "My updated title"
}` would successfully replace the existing data with the new data.

Comment: Where is update method defined?

Comment: From Repository in TypeORM [link](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/entity-manager-api)